# MS .NET images do not pull to Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Home

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I installed Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Home.
In, the Settings/General, option "Use the WSL 2 based engine (Windows Home can only run the WSL 2 backend) is checked and disabled (greyed out)

When I try to pull some Microsoft .NET images like

```
 pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples
```

I get responses like this:

```
 Using default tag: latest
 latest: Pulling from dotnet/framework/samples
 no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Does it mean that I cannot pull any images that are Windows/.NET specific? Is there some Docker alternative for Windows Home?

Comment: Read carefully _no matching manifest for linux/amd64_. You have docker desktop running on Linux containers and dotnet framework running only on windows.

Comment: The question is whether you can run Windows container on Windows; if not then what is the point of having a Docker on Windows?

Comment: Docker came in two _types_ of virtualization: Windows or Linux, you have selected WSL2 (which is Linux) but you can switch to Windows (from the Docker icon menu select, switch to Windows containers) but this requires Hyperv-V installed which you don't have on Windows Home. See [Install Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#:~:text=The%20following%20hardware%20prerequisites%20are%20required%20to%20successfully%20run%20Client,enabled%20in%20the%20BIOS%20settings.)